# Python: variable with multiple lists concatenate into one list

Tags: python

I'm relatively new to Python and am working on a problem where I'm looking to create a variable that contains every word in a text file without period marks and commas. I have the variable with each word correctly edited, however the variable prints as a list for each word (in this case, this one variable contains 280 lists, each list with a word).

The code I'm working with is such:

```
import string

with open("pythonhow1.txt",'r') as file:

    content=file.read()
    s=content.split()
    for words in s:
        v=string.replace(words,',','')
        w=string.replace(v,'.','')
        z=w.split()
        print(z)
```

variable `s` provides one list with each word in the text file before the editing, and the for loop removes `'.'` and `','` marks. However when I print `z`, I get output that looks like this:

```
['Aenean']

['commodo']

['ligula']

['eget']

['dolor']

['Aenean']

['massa']
```

where each word is its own list, stored in variable `z`. Alternatively, I would like `z` to print 1 list with each word, looking something like this:

```
['Aenean','commodo','ligula','eget','dolor','Aenean','massa']
```

I've tried using `itertools` as some other posts have suggest, however that makes the problem worse by breaking each letter into a string, looking something like this: `['A','e','n','e','a','n']`

Would anyone have an idea on what to do to solve this? Thank you ahead of time!

Answer (score 0):

The last split is redundant. Moreover, the whole thing can be done much more elegantly with a list comprehension:

```
z = [w.replace(',.', '') for w in s]
print(z)
```

Comment: thanks for that, I had a similar thought doing something like that, but it doesn't work in my code. I'm wondering if this is because I'm using Python 2, and that this would work in Python 3. Would you happen to know if that's true, and if so, how this could be different in Python 2?

Comment: You have to be a  bit more specific about what exactly doesn't work

Comment: Apologies - as in, when z prints, it essentially prints the same output as the variable s, with words that have ',' and '.' still attached. Put differently, the replace function does not replace commas and periods with nothing.